Proving a matrix has rank 1
Let $A \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ be a matrix such that $\text{Trace}(A^*A)=n^2$ and $n$ is an eigenvalue.
Prove that the matrix has rank $1$.
I don’t know how to approach this problem. I think I might have to use the frobenius norm of a matrix and the fact that the matrix filled with $1$ has the same norm as my matrix $A$.

I think Schur Decomposition [https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition ] would help. The Schur form has only one element that is nonzero.

Welcome to MSE! Is this a homework problem, a contest problem, or something else? Including some context just like what you mentioned about your first approach to the problem or the source like I asked can make it so we know what tools to use or what tools to avoid, so that you can in a way help us help you, among other benefits.

In general $\sum |\lambda|^2 \leq \text{Trace}(A^*A)$ (the sum is over all the eigenvalues with their multiplicity) 
Proof: Using the Schur Triangularization there exists $U$ unitary matrix and $T$ upper triangularity matrix such as $A=UTU^*$.
Now $\text{Trace}(A^*A)=\text{Trace}(UT^*U^*UTU^*)=\text{Trace}(T^*T) \geq \sum |\lambda|^2$
Going back to the problem
$n^2+\sum_{\lambda \neq n}|\lambda|^2 \leq \text{Trace}(A^*A)=n^2$, therefore $A$ has eigenvalue $n$ with multiplicity of $1$ and all eigenvalues that are not equal to $n$ must be $0$, which implies $\text{rank}(A)=1$

$\operatorname{Trace}(A^*A)$ is at least the sum of $|\lambda|^2$ over eigenvalues counted with multiplicity. If this sum is $n^2$ and $n$ is an eigenvalue, then this eigenvalue has multiplicity $1$ and the only other eigenvalue is $0$ with multiplicity $n-1$. From here it is not too hard if you know the rank nullity theorem.

This answer is elementary, based solely on the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. In particular the Schur triangularization theorem is not applied.
Let $A=\{a_{ij}\}.$ Then
$$n^2={\rm Trace}\,(A^*A)=\sum_{i,j=1}^n|a_{ij}|^2$$ Assume $Av=nv,$ $v\neq 0.$ Thus $$nv_i=\sum_{j=1}^na_{ij}v_j$$ WLOG we may assume $\sum_i|v_i|^2=1.$ Then by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality we get $$n^2|v_i|^2=\left |\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}v_j\right |^2\le \sum_{j=1}^n|a_{ij}|^2,\quad i=1,2,\ldots, n\quad (*)$$
If one of the inequalities is strict then by summing over $i$ we get
$$n^2< \sum_{i,j=1}^n|a_{ij}|^2=n^2$$ which leads to a contradiction.
Thus we have equalities in $(*)$ for every $i.$ The equality in the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality implies that the vector
$(a_{i1},a_{i2},\ldots,a_{in})^t$ is a multiple of the vector $\overline{v}$ for every $i.$ Thus the matrix $A$ has rank $1.$
Moreover the formula $Av=nv$ gives $$a_{ij}=n\overline{v_j}v_i $$
